# How can I access the shell of the AWS Lambda images on ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I wanted to install some dependencies for my lambda function to use. The original pipeline used the amazonlinux:2 docker image, where we install the dependencies on it and then package it and upload using serverless.

While this was working for python3.7, this is breaking for python versions >3.7 as mentioned [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bluesentry/bucket-antivirus-function/issues/113), which says its probably because python3.8 and higher don't have amazonlinux as base image.

So I wanted to use the closest base image possible, and use `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8`.

I get the following error for my commands though,

> docker run public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
> output: entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument

> docker run --rm \
> --volumes-from src \
> public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 \
> /bin/bash -c "cd $(container_dir) && sh build_lambda.sh"
> output:entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument

But a dockerfile with commands like below works when I run `docker build`.

> FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
>
> // Set up working directories
> RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
> RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/build
> RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/bin/
> ...

I want to be able to do that with shell, so running this image as a container, accessing its shell without a Dockerfile. The current pipeline puts the shell commands in build_lambda.sh and I don't want to change it too much.

Any better recommended approach would also be welcome

Comment: Try setting the entrypoint on the command line as empty by adding `--entrypoint ""`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> so running this image as a container, accessing its shell without a Dockerfile

If I understand correctly, you're looking to open a shell inside `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8`.

You can run:

```bash
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
```

You're then inside, free to run commands, which will look something like:

```bash
bash-4.2# pwd
/var/task
```